# How to link my buttons to the correct place

Tags: html, css

Ok So I'm doing a website in HTML/Css
The problem is that when I click on the  "Home" button it directs me to my css link. 
My mainpage is called "new.html" and that's where I want it to go when I click "home" instead of background.css
This is my "New.html"

```
    <html>
    <head>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="background.css"/>
    </head>
    <h1>Bully-Free Zone</h1>
    <h2>"Online harassment has an off-line impact"</h2>
    <a href="background.css" class="nav-link">Home</a>
    </body>
    </html>
```

background.css

```
body{/* IE10 */ 
background-image: -ms-linear-gradient(top left, #FC5B5B 0%, #555BB5 100%);

/* Mozilla Firefox */ 
background-image: -moz-linear-gradient(top left, #FC5B5B 0%, #555BB5 100%);

/* Opera */ 
background-image: -o-linear-gradient(top left, #FC5B5B 0%, #555BB5 100%);


/* Webkit (Chrome 11+) */ 
background-image: -webkit-linear-gradient(top left, #FC5B5B 0%, #555BB5 100%);

/* Proposed W3C Markup */ 
background-image: linear-gradient(top left, #FC5B5B 0%, #555BB5 100%);
}
h1{color:black;text-align:center;font-size:40px;font-family:broadway;
}
h2{color:black; text-align:center;font-size:35px;font-style:italic;}
a{color:black; text-align:left; font-size:25px;font-family:broadway;}
a.nav-link:link
{
 color: black;
 text-decoration: none;
}
a.nav-link:visited
{
 color: black;
 text-decoration: none;
}
a.nav-link:hover
{
   color: black;
   text-decoration: none;
}
a.nav-link:active
{
   color: black;
   text-decoration: none;
}
```

Comment: There are so many things I want to say in response to this question, but, genuinely, I'm trying not to be overly critical. Out of (sincere) curiosity, though, where did you learn HTML? Your CSS seems fine, but using your CSS-file in the `href` of the `a`? ...why..? What prompted that?

Comment: Well I bought a book at fries and everytime I have a problem I refer to w3schools.
What do you think I should insert instead of href a?
I am open for any criticism as it will help me learn, please don't hesitate. Give me pointers

Comment: Well, I'd suggest using the [Mozilla Developer Network's HTML resources](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/HTML) instead of W3Schools. But a `href` attribute is *only* used for where you want an element to link to. I'm confused as to why you thought it necessary to use an `href` to link to the CSS when you clearly wanted it to link to the home-page.

Comment: So I shouldn't use href to link to my home page, then what should I use instead?

Comment: I have no idea where this misunderstanding is coming from, I'm saying that you ***should absolutely*** use the `href` to link to the home-page. My... *concerns* ...are about your decision to use the `href` to link to your CSS, and then your surprise when it linked to your CSS.

Comment: Oh yes I initially thought that the href="background.css" was that
so my html and css could link to eachother but then I remembered that 
that's what the class="nav-link" was for.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is not obvious? Change this:

```
<a href="background.css" class="nav-link">Home</a>
```

to this:

```
<a href="new.html" class="nav-link">Home</a>
```

The computer only does what it's been told to do.

Comment: Oh I'm sorry I thought you needed the background.css in order to direct it there. But obviously it's already recognizing my css by
Class="nav-link"
Really sorry for this

Comment: The apology isn't necessary, as this website is a place to troubleshoot and learn. However, do remember to accept the answer if it was helpful.

Comment: Yes I will accept it. I just didn't want to be banned or something like that for not noticing such an easy mistake

Answer (score 1):

Change

```
<a href="background.css" class="nav-link">Home</a>
```

to:

```
<a href="new.html" class="nav-link">Home</a>
```

You should also insert

```
<body>
```

before your

```
<h1>
```

Answer (score 0):

Change this line:

```
<a href="background.css" class="nav-link">Home</a>
```

to

```
<a href="new.html" class="nav-link">Home</a>
```